# Track web application access through windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, http, port

I have a web application running on Amazon EC2 accessed on the port 80. I would like to track the  users who have accessed my application via windows server log.

However when i go on the logs i can only see  RDP access trackings or some internal logins like SQL SERVER Agent .

Do you know how to get this information on the server ?

[image]

Comment: What log(s) are you looking at exactly?

Comment: I added the picture of where i read the logs.

Comment: OK, IIS doesn't log to the Security Event Log. You need to look at the IIS log(s).

Comment: I am on tomcat webserver

Comment: Then you need to look at whatever logs Tomcat provides.

Comment: Yes that is the right response . Thank you i got what i wanted .

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i am using Tomcat server for my web application , i just went to he application log and found the ip addresses trying access the system . Also it shows what was the requested page and what was the response from the server .